# Google Add-on adding menu items in limited mode app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

We have a addon published in the new google app scripts add on store, but permissions don't seem to work correctly when using the add on in any spreadsheet other than the initial one it is installed in.

I'm seeing an issue where when a new spreadsheet is created and a user selects 'use this add on' from the 'manage add-ons' menu, our menu items don't get populated. For now we've been telling people to remove the add-on and reinstall to force the permissions flow for full permissions.

I looked at the permissions lifecycle guide at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#opening and it appears that our onOpen function should be able to add the menu items in LIMITED permissions mode:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem("About OurApp", 'aboutOurApp');
  menu.addItem("Show Sidebar", "showSidebar");
  menu.addToUi();
  Logger.log(e);
  if (e && (e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE || e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED)) {
    return; // once user selects a menu item, full permissions should be asked for according to docs.
  } else {
   // we have full permissions - show the sidebar.
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
     .setTitle('Our App');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
  }
}
```

Anyone know what we are doing wrong?

Comment: What evidence leads you to conclude that there's a permissions problem? (You don't describe what the expected & observed behaviors are.) Curious... why would you have `onOpen()` show the sidebar, when you've also got a `showSidebar()` function? (That would be pretty impolite behavior for an add-on, wouldn't it?)

Comment: The onInstall and onOpen functions both attempt to populate the spreadsheet menu with items. I'm seeing that those items only get added when the spreadsheet is first installed (post permissions grant). Expected behavior would be for the menu items to be installed after a user selects "use this add-on in this spreadsheet'. I show the sidebar so the user can interact with the app. They may choose to close the sidebar later (for view) and the menu item is there to give them access to the sidebar again.