# Google Apps Script - AuthMode - no menus are visible after installation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My app has been approved, and I am at the final approval that requires addon installation testing.

Here is what Google Docs ux team says

> "There appears to be a problem with the authMode setup - likely on the
>   onOpen function.  This causes the menu items to only appear on the
>   first doc the add-on is installed in.  Appears empty on all other docs
>   (screenshot attached).  For more info: 
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#opening"

Here is an unresolved similar issue [Google Add-on adding menu items in limited mode app scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002352/google-add-on-adding-menu-items-in-limited-mode-app-scripts)
Now, I am not doing anything special in onOpen and onInstall, just textbook stuff. Any tips? (redacted the menu titles...)

```
function onOpen(e) {

  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('menu1...', 'showSidebar')
    .addItem('Buyxxxxx', 'showSales')
    .addItem('Getting Started', 'showIntro')
    .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
 *     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
 *     AuthMode.NONE.)
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning here helped https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Need to look at console for errors, and I found one:

> Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call getPublicCache

Comment: Don't you have any global code that needs permission? When I had this issue, I had a call to SpreadsheetApp that was in a global comment. Looks like even comments can interfere with the Authorization.

Comment: It turned out I had a cache wrapper that was defined via object literal! So, I dumped the object literal notation and resorted to Constructor notation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356994/literal-notation-vs-constructor-to-create-objects-in-javascript