# How can I change my script to AuthMode.LIMITED in my Google Scripts code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

I was trying to publish a new version of an Add-on that was already created, but when I tried to publish it, I can see the menus, sub-menus and I can execute the Add-On [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcAuG.png). The problem is that the other users -*who before were able to execute the Add-On*- now they don't see the sub-menus and obviously they can't execute the Add-On [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKIfV.png).

I Googled a little bit and I was investigating about this, so I found that there is a method called AuthMode.NONE and AuthMode.LIMITED, I know the differences between them but I don't know how Google Scripts classify the Add-Ons and how to `force` change the AuthMode to LIMITED, or maybe you can give me another solution that can help.

BTW: I already checked if the Add-On is activated for my document and yes it is, I mean that i have the option: **Add-Ons --> Manage Add-Ons --> [my addon] --> Manage --> Use in this document** checked.

PD: I tried uninstalling and installing the Add-On, publishing and re-publishing new versions, I tried a lot of things but no solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post the screenshots here, as opposed to a link to them? It's just easier to read the question that way, instead of following you around with links.

Comment: Sorry @Farini I am new here, actually that what I did but the editor put me a link instead of the picture because of low reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This read on [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) may help:

> If an add-on is installed for a user but not enabled in the current
>   document, onOpen(e) runs in AuthMode.NONE; if the add-on is enabled in
>   the current document, onOpen(e) runs in AuthMode.LIMITED. If the
>   add-on is both installed and enabled, the enabled state takes
>   precedence, since LIMITED allows access to more Apps Script services.
>
> Note that only published add-ons can be in AuthMode.NONE; scripts that
>   are bound to a document, including add-ons in development, always run
>   onOpen(e) in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can, however, test a script as an
>   add-on to verify that an add-on under development will behave as
>   intended in either AuthMode.

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137753/google-apps-script-authmode-no-menus-are-visible-after-installation) for additional reference.